# sql- Show each month as field name for sum(qty) of items

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum, sql-view

I'd like to show each month's sum qty for the month correspondingly

```
ItemCode | October | November  |  December |  January
 PZ         0         0            12          36
```

So far my query looks like [image]

And my SQL is

```
SELECT Detail.ItemCode
    ,SUM(Detail.QuantityOrdered) AS Total_Quantity
    ,MonthName(Month([Header.OrderDate])) AS ['Month Name']
FROM Detail
INNER JOIN Header ON Detail.SalesOrderNo = Header.SalesOrderNo
WHERE Header.OrderDate >= dateadd("m", - 4, DATE ())
GROUP BY Detail.ItemCode
    ,Header.OrderDate
ORDER BY SUM(Detail.QuantityOrdered) DESC;
```

And my `Header.OrderDate` looks like 12/25/2016.

Should I use `crossover`? I have looked up a lot but none seems applicable.. Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: probably Transform does a better job - http://ss64.com/access/transform.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jayvee mentioned, `Transform` looks promising.

Alternatively, you can do conditional aggregation, been a while since I worked with Access, but something like this:

```
    SELECT Detail.ItemCode
        , SUM(CASE WHEN Month([Header.OrderDate]) = 1 THEN Detail.QuantityOrdered END) AS 'January'
        , SUM(CASE WHEN Month([Header.OrderDate]) = 2 THEN Detail.QuantityOrdered END) AS 'February'
        , SUM(CASE WHEN Month([Header.OrderDate]) = 3 THEN Detail.QuantityOrdered END) AS 'March'        
    FROM Detail
    INNER JOIN Header ON Detail.SalesOrderNo = Header.SalesOrderNo
    WHERE Header.OrderDate >= dateadd("m", - 4, DATE ())
    GROUP BY Detail.ItemCode
    ORDER BY Detail.ItemCode;
```

Edit: Looks like `Transform` handles it dynamically already, something like this:

```
TRANSFORM SUM(Detail.QuantityOrdered)
SELECT Detail.ItemCode
FROM Detail
INNER JOIN Header ON Detail.SalesOrderNo = Header.SalesOrderNo
WHERE Header.OrderDate >= dateadd("m", - 4, DATE ())
GROUP BY Detail.ItemCode
PIVOT MonthName(Month([Header.OrderDate]))
```

Not sure if it will handle the function in the `PIVOT` you may need a subquery to get the monthname or other workaround.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there anyway that I can set the MonthName dynamically? For example, on February, It will start from November to Feb :) Thank you so so much!

Comment: And my apologies that I wasn't clear on it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JohnTipton It looks like `TRANSFORM` may handle it dynamically already, not confident that my attempt is correct, but a starting point at the least.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! As a fellow Denverite, I sincerely appreciate your response! Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that what you are looking for is unpivot, but it does not exist in MS-Acess.

The simplest way to replicate would be something like this:

```
SELECT ItemCode, October as Total_Quantity, 'October' as MonthName
UNION                     
SELECT ItemCode, November as Total_Quantity, 'November' as MonthName
UNION                     
SELECT ItemCode, December as Total_Quantity, 'December'as MonthName
UNION                    
SELECT ItemCode, January as Total_Quantity, 'January' as MonthName
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there anyway that I can set the MonthName dynamically? For example, on February, It will start from November to Feb :) Thank you so so much!

Comment: As far as I know in Access I doubt it's possible. In this case I would extend the UNION until they cover the 12 months.

Comment: OP can correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe he has the date field and wants to generate aggregates by month, rather than having a field per month and wanting to combine them.